# SQL order by and SQL date

Tags: mysql

I have 2 doubts related to SQL query's

```
id name update
1  some  2013-05-03
2  som   2013-05-08
3  smee  2013-06-05
```

1. How can i list items on a particular month (I want all records,year and date will not be specified I just want to check the month)
2. How can I arrange name in alphabetic order and arrange it as groups of names such as (limiting number of records =10)

Array A = names starting with A
Array B = names starting with B

Comment: What is the datatype of `update` field?

Comment: The data type is DATE

Comment: And the date do not have `05` or `03` there? Just `2013-5-3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way, to fetch `MONTH` from a `DATE` or `DATETIME` type of fields is to use the MySQL's date-time function [`MONTH()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month).

For your query, it shall be:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblName
WHERE MONTH( `update` ) = <month Number such as 5>
```

---

The second would need a more complex query. I'd rather use php to do the grouping better(as I've more control over that language).

Comment: @RahulR Since @Dream-Eater gave the answer I wanted to make, I'll answer here for the second. You got 3 solutions : Make multiple request (which I don't advise you to do), make your query and group with the server language of your choice or `SELECT `id`, `name`, `update`, SUBSTRING(`name`,1,1) as initial FROM tblName ORDER BY initial` which will be easier to parse later on. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a582/3

Comment: @Shikiryu Now that you mention it, a `GROUP_CONCAT` can also work.

Comment: @DreamEater yes, if he wants it in a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use datatype of the field as `DATE` or you can store any date as [**unix timestamp**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) and then convert it whenever you want to show it.

```
Example: 1363979714 (ISO 8601:2013-03-22T19:15:14Z)
```

If you want list items on a particular date, you can write your query like this:

Month:

```
 Select * from tableName where update like '%-5-%'
```

day:

```
 Select * from tableName where update like '%-16'
```

year:

```
 Select * from tableName where update like '2013-%'
```